# Humorous Sci fi about invaders from mars

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book read in the 1980s. The plot is that alien invaders have taken over earth.  They have paranormal powers in that they can teleport. Their motives are unknown but most of them just choose a random human being to follow and irritate.  I don't recall much about it except it s written in  very funny way.  One scene is when our protagonist asks his particular Martian about another guy who was hanging around the protagonists girl.  He describes his final and adds that his rival "always wears suits".  The Martian disappears and reappears,  and informs theft that his description was wrong,  as  he did see a man with the hero's girl,  but must be a different person,  as "he can't be your rival,  cause this guy wasnt in a suit,  he was clad in nothing but a wrist watch!"

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like the classic *[Martians Go Home](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1560)* by Fredric Brown. One review [says](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/246028967)

> The martians, and there are millions of them, have come to earth not to conquer, but to amuse themselves. They can teleport anywhere they want and see through objects. But anyone who tries to kick a martian finds their foot going through empty space. The martians have no material substance.
> Mass chaos breaks out as humanity has to concern itself with little green men who appear everywhere, making fun of people.

There's also a movie based on the book. Avoid it, it's terrible.

Comment: That sounds exactly like the book!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Seconded on both book and movie. Book is great fun. Movie is too bad to be enjoyable, and I *like* bad movies.